# log4j - Why is logger.debug not working?

Tags: xml, debugging, logging, configuration, log4j

My log4j.xml file has the following config:

```
   <appender name="fileAppender"
           class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
      <!-- Change Log File Root when Environment is Set Up -->
      <param name="File" value="${root}/application.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <logger name="db.scheduler" additivity="false" >
      <level value="all"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
   </logger>
```

However. when I do logger.debug, it doesn't add anything! logger.info and logger.error work... but not logger.debug!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
```

Your threshold is set to `INFO`, that's one level *below* `DEBUG`, so any debug messages won't make it through the filter. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log_level) for the relative levels:

```
Level       Description
=====       ===========
OFF         The highest possible rank and is intended to
            turn off logging.
FATAL       Severe errors that cause premature termination.
            Expect these to be immediately visible on a
            status console.
ERROR       Other runtime errors or unexpected conditions.
            Expect these to be immediately visible on a
            status console.
WARN        Use of deprecated APIs, poor use of API,
            'almost' errors, other runtime situations that
            are undesirable or unexpected, but not
            necessarily "wrong". Expect these to be
            immediately visible on a status console.
INFO        Interesting runtime events (startup or
            shutdown). Expect these to be immediately
            visible on a console, so be conservative
            and keep to a minimum.
DEBUG       Detailed information on the flow through
            the system. Expect these to be written to logs
            only.
TRACE       Most detailed information. Expect these to be
            written to logs only. Since version 1.2.12.
```

Comment: So I should change it to ALL ?

Comment: @gran_profaci, no. If you want debug messages, change it to `debug`. `all` will give you trace messages as well (which you may well want but your question asked specifically about `logger.debug`). If you want to see everything, and don't mind wading through a lot of data, by all means use tracing as well.